# Capital Gain on sale of shares

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, form-1040

I have sold shares held by me in Pakistan. My holding was for more than a year. Do I need report this on my US Form 1040 for 2021 tax year? How do I report it ie where and how on Form 1040?

Comment: Why are you a US taxpayer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly an expert, but if you are a US citizen or resident, I'll wager that a Schedule D form will be one of the forms involved.

Then it gets more complicated. Were you also taxed by Pakistan on this transaction? If so, this article covers some ways to deal with the double taxation:

https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/012214/understanding-taxation-foreign-investments.asp

Many of the better places for efiling returns are set up to ask about various sources and types of income, including offshore income. Based on your answers, the (usually) correct forms are selected.

I had my own complications with offshore income and US capital gains this year. I finally gave up trying to calcuate my actual tax due this year and used an online filing service to handle the final calculation. Hopefully, it was correct. :-)

Answer (score -2):

I am not a tax professional, but I can provide some general information. Please consult a tax advisor or the IRS for specific guidance related to your situation.

Generally, if you are a U.S. citizen or resident alien, you are required to report all income, including capital gains, on your U.S. federal income tax return (Form 1040) regardless of where the income was earned.

To report the sale of shares held for more than a year on your Form 1040 for the 2021 tax year, you would likely need to use Schedule D: Capital Gains and Losses. Here are the general steps to report the sale:

Complete Form 8949: Sales and Other Dispositions of Capital Assets. This form is used to report the details of each individual sale transaction.
Transfer the totals from Form 8949 to Schedule D.
Calculate the overall capital gain or loss on Schedule D by summarizing the transactions.
Transfer the resulting capital gain or loss to the appropriate section on your Form 1040.